# Select2() is not a function with Select2 4.0.11

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

I realize there is a question with a similar problem. However, none of the solutions fixed my issues. I am using JQuery Select2 to implement a searchable dropdown:

```
<label for="interface_id" class="col-form-label required">Interface With </label>
<select id="interface_id" name="interface_id" class="form-control chosen-select" required="required">
<option value="2169010"> Not Applicable</option>
<option value="1799">TOOL</option>
<option value="1129">Review</option>
<option value="554">web</option>
</select>
```

The js is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.chosen-select').select2();}
```

This throws the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function

I suspect it's due to conflict with some other JQuery or JS libraries. This is the list of the scripts I am loading:

```
<!-- scripts -->
<script src="/apm/static/js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="/apm/static/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/apm/static/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="/apm/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/apm/static/js/bootstrap-4-navbar.js"></script>
<script src="/apm/static/js/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="/apm/static/js/js.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="/apm/static/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/apm/static/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="/apm/static/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/apm/static/js/dataTables.searchHighlight.min.js"></script>
<script src="/apm/static/js/jquery.highlight.js"></script>
<script src="/apm/static/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="/apm/static/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="/apm/static/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="/apm/static/js/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="/apm/static/js/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="/apm/static/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="/apm/static/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="/apm/static/js/masterScreen.js"></script>
<script src="/apm/static/js/select2.js"></script>
<script src="/apm/static/js/interfaces.js"></script>
<!-- end scripts -->
```

How do I fix this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try to use cdn <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.11/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.11/js/select2.min.js"></script> and check again

Comment: I can only use local js

Comment: yes but if you check and it work then just need to download and use. (this is just a one case for testing)

Comment: I am guessing you are using select2.js from select2.org within datatables, which will not work. You need to obtain the select2.js from datatables.net site.